# Pop a value when it is not checked : checkbox

Tags: jquery

I use this method for getting values of my checkbox. So I want know, how can I do for pop value when I uncheck one checkbox:

My method:

```
$('.selectionne:checked').each(function(){
   elems.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: **Tip:** You can use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Sorry Spokey :) .. pop value mine remove a value in my array when he is unchecked

Comment: you can find the index of the element in the array using Array.indexOf() then use Array.splice() to remove it

Comment: Thanks Arun, but please can you write the code for me please ?

Comment: Another option I prefer is to recreate the array when I want like `var elems = $('.selectionne').filter(':checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q4GaB/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$('.selectionne').change(function(){
   this.checked ? elems.push(this.id) : elems.pop(this.id);
});
```

This is just a shorthand for checking whether the checkbox you clicked has been checked or not - if it is, add it's ID to the array, else pop it's ID from the array.

[jsFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/v2UjW/)